# Using Predict to fill in missing data

Tags: list-manipulation, data, machine-learning

I am attempting to use Predict[] to fill in the missing data in the dataset below;

```
 training = {{1.3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 87, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 2, 4, 7, 7, 
"P"} -> 1, {1.8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 2, 5, 7, 8, 2, 2, 0, 1, 
"Q"} -> 2.5}


p = Predict[training, Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]
```

Heres a test set

```
test = {1.8, Missing[], 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, Missing[], 4, 2, 5,6, Missing[], "P"}
```

When try to use the function p for the test set;

```
p[test]
```

only the first value is returned; 1

How can i use Predict[] to find all the missing data values within the test set?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems.

There is an extra level of nesting in `regressionInput` so `Flatten` it first.

```
Predict[regressionInput // Flatten, Method -> "LinearRegression"]
```

That reveals the second problem

> Predict::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and
>   variable value ().

The input is a mix of numeric values and an `RGBColor`. `Predict` cannot handle mixed data types as inputs. You can try `Predict` on the numerics and the colors independently, but of course that will not work if they are correlated in some way.

Comment: Thank you Rohit, your reply does make sense. I've updated the question so that its a more suitable problem